# TeleBot | reply_to_message в группе

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

`TeleBot`| `message.reply_to_message` не работает в группе. Если боту в личные сообщения переслать ,то всё функционирует штатно.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command1'])
def command1(message):
    if hasattr(message.reply_to_message, 'text'):
        print(message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
```

Пример сообщение :

```
    [В ответ на Тестовый Юзер Для Примера]
    /command1@ThankUForAnswer_Bot

Сам реплай(от Тестовый Юзер Для Примера) : gfjeriufhe
Вот пример:
```

[image: Пример]

Но,если переслать сообщение вида `/command1@ThankUForAnswer_Bot`,то всё работает.
[image: Пример2]

В чем заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

бот должен быть админом группы

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не дошло проверить)